# How to use REST Assured to upload a file?

Tags: java, integration-testing, rest-assured

I wrote a service which can upload a file to the server, and now I'm writing it's integration test with REST Assured. The functional code is as following:

```
    /* Upload a new document */
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity uploadDocument(@RequestPart("file") final MultipartFile file, final HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        final String id = documentService.saveDocument(file);
        final String url = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort() + "/documents/" + id;
        return ControllerUtil.resourceCreatedMessage(id, url);
    }
```

To use this service, I always upload a file in Postman, and I didn't add "Content-Type = multipart/form-data" in the Headers, it works perfectly:
[image]

If I add the header info "Content-Type = multipart/form-data", I will get the message that "400 - Request is not a multipart request, see details for more information". This part also confused me because in the upper image you can see I'm sending a file in "form-data", how could it not be a multipart request?

Anyway, I am writing the integration test:

```
@Test
public void testDocuments() throws URISyntaxException {
    // Test post a document.
    given().multiPart("file", new File(LOCATE_TO_THE_TEST_HTML_FILE))
            .expect().statusCode(201).when()
            .post(HOST + "/documents");
}
```

but I got the 415 error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <201> doesn't match actual status code <415>.

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:451)
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate$1.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1632)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:812)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1637)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:812)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:170)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at integrationTest.DocumentsIT.testDocuments(DocumentsIT.java:29)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I tried to add ".contentType("multipart/form-data")" but the same error occured. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe you need a `@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally found the reason that I should specify the data type of the file in the following way:

```
.multiPart("file", new File(TestUtil.getFileURI("/examples/help.html")), "text/html")
```

Comment: Tested, it works.   We can get file from context like this: >>>>   

context.parse(Form.class)
                .map(form -> new FileAttachmentRequestPayload(form.get("data"), form.files("file")))

Answer (score 4):

This is a way where I can send the video in post API using multipart.

```
File file = new File("File Path");
String endpoint = "/api/v3/abc";    

   RestAssured.baseURI = "http://dummy.com/";
        Response res = given()
                .formParam("token", "eacca99696ac5")
                .multiPart("media_url", file,"application/json")
                .when().post(endpoint);
```

Answer (score 1):

So In my point I needed to upload 2 files and also Json file

[image]

This how i success to solve it:
when `file1` and `file2` are the Path to the files

```
public static Response Post(JSONObject body, String URL, String file1, String file2) {
        try {
            return RestAssured.given().baseUri(URL).urlEncodingEnabled(false)
                    .accept("application/json, text/plain, */*")
                    .multiPart("data",body,"application/json")
                    .multiPart("file[0]", new File(file1),"multipart/form-data")
                    .multiPart("file[1]", new File(file2),"multipart/form-data")
                    .relaxedHTTPSValidation().when().post();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```