# How to send a POST with form-data in Body in RestAssured setting multipart with a specific content-type

Tags: java, automated-tests, rest-assured

Trying to send a POST request with form-data in Body in RestAssured, however not sure how should do it.
In Postman, it's fine.

[image]

I've tried things like:

```
public Response create() {
    return super
            .given()
            .contentType("multipart/form-data")
            .multiPart("MetaDataOne", new File("file.txt"))
            .multiPart("MetaDataTwo", new File("file2.txt"))
            .basePath("/create")
            .log().all()
            .post()
            .then()
            .log().all()
            .extract()
            .response();
}
```

But seems that my files are not being sent in the request.

**Console log**

Multiparts

- Content-Disposition form-data; name = MetadataOne; filename = file
- Content-Type: application/octet-stream

{"error": 415, "description": Content type application/octet-stream not supported}

Headers
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use REST Assured to upload a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39482473/how-to-use-rest-assured-to-upload-a-file)

Comment: Hi thanks for the anwser! In that link, we need to add - .multiPart("file", new File(TestUtil.getFileURI("/examples/help.html")), "text/html"), but TestUtil.getFileURI is not recognized

Comment: Ive understood my issue, still have to understand how to fix it hehe.. So what is happening is that by standard my "multiPart" is setting its content-type as "application/octet-stream". But the correct one should be "application/json"

Comment: Can you post the curl request that is generated by postman here ? it'll help a bit

Comment: hi, ive added more infos in the description as I cannot share the url :) Thanks for helping

Comment: That's alright, and how about the headers ? can you share those which you post from POSTMAN ? If application/octet-stream is not supported I need to know what POSTMAN is sending,
Is it multipart/form-data

Comment: Yes, in postman, the Header is sending: Content-Type as "multipart/form-data". And works, doesnt work when I try send it in Rest Assured (same test that I post in descripition)

Comment: hi, added a print with the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with this, This should overwrite the Content-Type as `multipart/form-data` rather than `application/octet-stream`

```
given().contentType("multipart/form-data").multiPart("MetaDataOne", new File("file.txt"), "multipart/form-data")
                .multiPart("MetaDataTwo", new File("file2.txt"), "multipart/form-data").basePath("/create").log().all()
                .post().then().log().all().extract().response();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to consume a RESTFull webservice Api, just follow these simple steps

**Step 1: Create a Request Object pointing to the Service**

```
RestAssured.baseURI ="https://myhost.com/xyz";
RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();
```

**Step 2: Create a JSON object which contains all the form fields**

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("Form_Field_1", "Input Value 1"); 
jsonObject.put("Form_Field_2", "Input Value 2");
jsonObject.put("Form_Field_3", "Input Value 3");
jsonObject.put("Form_Field_4", "Input Value 4");
```

**Step 3: Add JSON object in the request body and send the Request**

```
request.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.body(jsonObject.toJSONString());
```

**Post the request and check the response**

```
Response response = request.post("/register");
```

**Step 4: Validate the Response**

```
int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
```

Comment: Ive understood my issue, still have to understand how to fix it hehe.. So what is happening is that by standard my "multiPart" is setting its content-type as "application/octet-stream". But the correct one should be "application/json"

Comment: Exactly! which is the first line in Step 3  - request.header("Content-Type", "application/json")

Comment: yes, but seems I need two different sets. First one is set the contentType for Header as "multipart/form-data", which is fine to do. The Second set Im not sure yet how to do, as I need to set for the each multipart a different contentType, that should be "application/json"

Comment: @Jimmy With all due respect this answer is no way related to the question, Step 2 is only going to generate a Json payload which is not the OP's requirement